# Jackson POJOPropertyBuilder finds conflicting setter definition when junit test run with cobertura

Tags: unit-testing, junit, jackson, swagger, cobertura

I have written a junit test which passes when run standalone but throws an exception when the cobertura test coverage tool is used.

The class under test tries to create a new instance of io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig:

```
BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
...
beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

But throws this exception **only** when run with cobertura

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "clazz": net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.LightClassmapListener#setClazz(1 params) vs net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.LightClassmapListener#setClazz(1 params)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:303)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:264)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:151)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:85)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:131)
at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolveProperty(ModelResolver.java:93)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolveProperty(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:65)
at io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters.readAsProperty(ModelConverters.java:58)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.ParameterProcessor.applyAnnotations(ParameterProcessor.java:112)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.getParameters(Reader.java:897)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.parseMethod(Reader.java:848)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:286)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:169)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.Reader.read(Reader.java:146)
at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setScan(BeanConfig.java:170)
```

Is there a means to get the swagger scan to ignore this cobertura class?
Inspection of the decompiled code shows that the boolean passed to beanConfig.setScan is completely ignored so setting that to false has no effect.

Comment: I am using swagger-jersey2-jaxrs version 1.5.0

Comment: Upgrading to swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.12 seems to fix this issue...

Comment: Thanks @Troup, fixed it for me!